# Tool tip is not woking when hovering over mat-item in side nav

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Tool tip is not working in the side nav bar after adding the content.Here is the code I have so far https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-jexssm?file=app/sidenav-autosize-example.html

Comment: You haven't added tooltip code in your html

Comment: Add `matTooltip="Your tooltip string here"` to your `mat-icon` as  `<mat-icon matTooltip="Your tooltip string here" mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>` and it works perfectly in your stackblitz code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/) example for your help. But i want to tell your you haven't used the tooltip code in your html code. :) Kindly mark it as Answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**HTML Code**

```
 <mat-sidenav  matTooltip="Your tooltip string here" 
     #tooltip="matTooltip">
     ......
 </mat-sidenav>
```

See this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcvri8-dcqmtd?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html

Comment: Why are you getting a redundant instance to the tooltip?

Comment: you can show tooltip dynamically using that reference

Comment: But isn't the tooltip bound to the sidenav then?

Comment: you can add matTooltip="Your tooltip string here"  this to any tag of material that will work you haven't seen the link that I gave?

Comment: I'm referring to the code that you answered with, not the StackBlitz.